# Returning an object from a method in C#

Tags: c#

I want to return an object as the result of a calculation in a method but I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConsoleApp2Iteration.LoanOut' to 'double". The "return new LoanOut" is underlined. What is going wrong? I need the three outputs (InterestPaymentAnnual etc.) as input to other calculations elsewhere.

```
public class Loan
{  
 > initialisers here  
    public double LoanCalc()
    {
        double nper = LoanYrs * NprPrYr;//payment terms per yr  
 `double EffectiveRate = Math.Pow(1 + (InterestPct + ContribPct),  
(Math.Pow(NprPrYr, -1))) - 1;`   
//interest per payment term
        double Interest_Contribution = InterestPct + ContribPct;
        double length = nper;
        double InterestPaymentP1 = 0;
        {
            Pymnt = Financial.Pmt(EffectiveRate, nper, LoanNPV, 0, 0);
            LoanOutstanding = LoanNPV;           
        for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
             {
// code block removed for clarity   
            if (i % NprPrYr != 0)
// testing for full years as derived calculations use input inyears                    
                    {
                    InterestPaymentAnnual += Interest_ContributionUSD;
                    RePymntAnnual += RePymnt;
                    }
            else
                   {
                    InterestPaymentAnnual += Interest_ContributionUSD;
                    RePymntAnnual += RePymnt;
 // new object which containts annual interest payment, annual repayment and    
 //   remaining loan amount
                   return new LoanOut(InterestPaymentAnnual, RePymntAnnual,    
                    LoanOutstanding);
 //initialisation before new payment cycle
                    InterestPaymentAnnual = 0;
                    RePymntAnnual = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return InterestPymntP1;
    }
}

public class LoanOut
{
    public double InterestPaymentAnnual { get; private set; }
    public double RePymntAnnual { get; private set; }
    public double LoanOutstanding { get; private set; }
    double InterestPymntP1 = 0;
    double Repayment = 0;
    double DebtRemaining = 0;
     public LoanOut(double InterestPaymentAnnual, double RePymntAnnual, 
     double LoanOutstanding)
    {
        this.InterestPaymentAnnual = InterestPymntP1;
        this.RePymntAnnual = Repayment;
        this.LoanOutstanding = DebtRemaining;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show how your **LoanOut()** method looks?

Comment: @ Victor. There is no LoanOut method as yet, wanted to get the output procedure right before. The LoanOut class is listed at the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have stated, you are trying to return both a LoanOut instance, and a double.

```
return new LoanOut(InterestPaymentAnnual, RePymntAnnual, LoanOutstanding); //Returning LoanOut Instance
```

and

```
return InterestPymntP1; //Returning double
```

if you need (or want) to gain two values from a method call, you should look at `out` parameters.
EG.

```
public LoanOut LoanCalc(out double InterestPayment)
{
    //Your stuff here
}
```

You have to assign to `InterestPayment` for the calling code to use it.

Alternatively you can change your `LoanOut` class to also contain your 'InterestPayment' informaiton on that object. You would only NOT do that if the `InterestPayment` info doesn't relate to the `LoanOut` instance... which looking at it probably isn't the case.

Also, if you do fix this and keep the method structured as displayed in your question, You have unreachable code directly after the `return new LoanOut` line...

```
InterestPaymentAnnual = 0;
RePymntAnnual = 0;
```

will never get run

Comment: Is out parameters specifically limited to two values? I need at least three now, perhaps more. What are the benefits of out parameters as opposed to returning an object? Thx. I will look into unreachable code. U may have noticed this is a novice at work.

Comment: @Henrik Kragelund, no, you can make any parameter out, not just 1. Bare in mind you have to assign a value to an out parameter. You are nearly always better off returning an object with all your values, if the values relate to eachother.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is declared as returning a double and you have a statement

```
return new LoanOut(InterestPaymentAnnual, RePymntAnnual, LoanOutstanding);
```

Change the return type of your method to LoanOut:

```
public LoanOut LoanCalc()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have method `public double LoanCalc()` but you try to `return new LoanOut()`. So the error is correct, you can't convert `LoanOut` to `double`. Change the method signature to return `LoanOut`.

Also, if the pasted code formatting is what you have in your editor I would strongly suggest to reformat your code to make it more readable.

Comment: Thx for the input. It is hard to reformat though. Is there anything specific u think should be improved. Im very open to suggestions.

Comment: @HenrikKragelund Even simple thing such as indentation helps. {} in your sample are not aligned to the same column so it's hard to find out where each code block begins and ends. Or, you have opening { right after `double InterestPaymentP1 = 0;` line without any apparent reason. It just adds another block without good reason and makes code more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm reading this right, you want to return a LoanOut but you're getting the error that you are trying to convert from LoanOut to double. Your method, however specifically says that you'll be returning a double:

```
public double LoanCalc()
```

I would try replacing double with LoanOut like this:

```
public LoanOut LoanCalc()
```

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Only now I get "not all code paths return a value". I'll dig into that one.

Comment: That's because your return statement is in the "else." That means that your method will only return something if it reaches that else. Anytime there is a return value specified in the method definition, you basically need to have a return statement at the very end of the method. You can have more than one return statement but the method must lead to a return statement in order for the method to be valid.

Comment: OK. The program always ends up in the "else", which basically just contains a counter that returns the object when the "cup is full", ie. when crossing a full year. The bug now is that I can't reset the values before the return object bit, because it will return zeros. I can't have it after the return object bit, because the variables will not initialise for a new years counting.